# If Rumble uses a skill that gets him in the Danger Zone, is the skill empowered?

Tags: league-of-legends

> > [image: icon] Flamespitter:
>
> ACTIVE: Rumble activates his flamethrower for 3 seconds, dealing magic damage every 0.5 seconds to enemy units in a cone in front of him (dealing half damage to minions). Rumble can perform other actions while Flamespitter is active.
>
> DANGER ZONE:  Flamespitter's damage is increased by 50%.

Let's say I'm at 45 heat, and I decide to use the Flamespitter. I'm now at 65 heat, but will the Flamespitter hit with the increased 50% damage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short and sweet answer: No.

Danger Zone is checked when the ability is *cast*.

Likewise, an ability that causes Rumble to Overheat will still cast (even allowing the 2nd shot of Electro Harpoon, despite being locked out of other abilities).